# Saving appended elements to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've made a very simple shopping list with jquery here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.project-btn').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var project = $('.project-val').val();

$('<li></li>').addClass(project).text(project).appendTo('.project-list');

});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQxE7/ 
everything works great however when i reload the page everything that I've appended goes away.
I want to save the appened element so if someone else goes on the website they can what i have added to the list.

How would I save that sort of information to a database using php or mysqli?
Can I save an element as a string and then call back that string though PHP?

I've looked up on google but I got nothing that's why I am asking it here.

I don't need the code of how to do just how to go about it, thanks!

Comment: you can post the item using ajax to the database

Comment: @UDB no but I guess my question is more can I save an element to a database as a string? Then I'll just call that string with the element through php

Comment: You can save it as a string and get it back but if that is the best option?

Comment: @putvande I don't think it is that's why I'm asking here to see what is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.project-btn').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var project = $('.project-val').val();

$('<li></li>').addClass(project).text(project).appendTo('.project-list');

var elem={};
elem.str='<li class="'+project+'">'+project+'</li>';

$.ajax({

 url: 'path/to/your/phpscript.php',
 data: elem,
 type: 'POST',
 success: function(response)
 {
   //do whatever you like
 }

 })//end of ajax call

});
});
```

phpscript.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'your schema/database name');
define('DB_USER', 'your db user name');
define('DB_PASSWORD','password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$link)
{
 die('Could not connect: '.mysqli_error());
}

  $db_selected= mysqli_select_db($link,DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected)
{
  die('Cant use : '.mysqli_error());
}

 $sql="insert into yourtable values('$_POST[str]')";

 mysqli_query($link,$sql);

 mysqli_close($link);

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a table in database called Project. Every time you append things in your project-list also send with Ajax the details of the "project" to your database.

Then everytime your page loads make an Ajax request to your server and get the rows of Project table. Then you could use jQuery .each (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) and build your DOM so whoever and whenever someone opens your website it will be updated.

Hope it helps!

Comment: All the above with the help of PHP that will return you the database records as json

Answer (score 1):

Storing the complete HTML for something as trivial, and easy to accomplish might not really be a good idea.

What I would do is, store all the projects in the 'project-list' to a sql db, and then populate the list reading the values from the db. When you click a button, you could insert a new value in the db, via Ajax, then depending on the returned value, determine whether the insert was successful or not, and then create the element on the client side. Other users, who use the page, will anyway read the list from the table to populate their version of the lists, so it will get updated for their end too.

Comment: Thank You! you seem patient and understanding unlike some other people here

Comment: Learning new things is always a continuous process, and we each start and continue at our own pace. One just has to remember this much. While saying all that, I'l add that sometimes the others get impatient when people ask someone else to do their work, and won't bother researching enough or doing some basic web searches to find their own answers. Your Q was not too bad. There are others out there though, whose questions sometimes warrant the angst among others. Cheers