# Saving div with internal elements and showing to everybody

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have jQuery that makes `div` with internal elements on button click. I want that `div` to be saved in a table and show it to anybody that goes to that page.

I read this question [Saving appended elements to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558839/saving-appended-elements-to-database). Now I have two questions:

1. In that answer, it only shows for one element (`<li>`). How would I save other elements that are appended inside of my `div`? **Answered in edit below and in question's answer**
2. How would I load add those saved `div`s on page load? I thought to make PHP code that searches all rows with those elements from column and `echo` them on page load

[Full JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/csk61vru/1/)

Div that I want to save:

```js
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var p = document.createElement("P");
var line = document.createElement("HR");
var text = document.createElement("P");
div.className = 'container';
p.className = 'date';
p.id = 'demo';
line.className = 'line1';
text.id = "text";
text.className = "feedback-container-text";
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(p);
div.appendChild(line);
div.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "some text";
var d = new Date();
d.getDay();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
```

```css
.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13), 0 14px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}

.container:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: Your "Edited JS Fiddle" link does not seem to point to a JS Fiddle but rather to another SO page.

Comment: Also, I believe it should be `$sql->bindParam(':element', $div);` (you omitted a `:`).

Comment: What is the primary key of this table? If you have multiple div elements you want to save, how would you distinguish which is which? Have you thought this through?

Comment: @Booboo I have fixed link for JSFiddle and PHP, as you said. I only want one element **to be added** in table, per request, but all rows ( elements - divs ) to be extracted from table and shown. My primary key is set to A.I "FeedbackNum" as feedback number that is counting on itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the `innerHTML` attribute of the enclosing `<div>` tag

```
savedHTML = div.innerHTML;
// save to database
```

After that, add `<div>` and `</div>` with proper CSS to your string to input and store the string in the database.

**See Demo:**

```js
function Add() {
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var p = document.createElement("P");
var line = document.createElement("HR");
var text = document.createElement("P");
div.className = 'container';
p.className = 'date';
p.id = 'demo';
line.className = 'line1';
text.id = "text";
text.className = "feedback-container-text";
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.appendChild(p);
div.appendChild(line);
div.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "some text";
var d = new Date();
d.getDay();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;

savedHTML = div.innerHTML;
document.f["div-value"].value = savedHTML;
}
```

```css
.container {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 60px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13), 0 14px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.container:hover {
  width: 300px;
  height: 225px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<form name="f" action="">
  <!--Change type from 'text' to 'hidden' to hide it from users-->
  <!--and from 'button' to 'submit' so form would submit-->
  <input name="div-value" type="text" value="">
  <input name="add-button" type="button" id="add-button" value="Add DIV" onclick="Add()">
</form>
```

Note that in a real situation the `Add` function would complete by submitting the form to the following PHP script:

### PHP to add `div` to table

---

```
/*
 * Following 2 PHP codes have been provided by the OP to benefit other community 
 * members who might find them useful.
*/
try {
    // $dbh is connection to database

    $div = $_GET['div-value'];
    $div2 = '<div class="container">'.$div.'</div>';

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Feedback(Element) VALUES(:element)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':element', $div2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Insert successful!<br/>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: ",  $e->getMessage(), "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

And would retrieve all those `div`s with following PHP script:

### PHP to retrieve all `div`s from table

---

```
try {
 // $dbh is also connection to database
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Element FROM Feedback");
 if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      print_r($row["Element"]);
    }
 }
}
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error!: ",  $e->getMessage(), "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is this meaning that I should make a table that would store only `innerHTML` of every div and set restore function on page load to retrieve data from that table. Also, how would I get PHP to work when retrieving data from table when I reload a page?

Comment: First, I believe you were talking about a div with internal elements. It is this *most enclosing* div whose innerHTML you take and store. If you have other, similar div elements that you need to do the same thing for, then of course you would do the same thing for them. To actually load the div, one way would be for the JavaScript code to make an Ajax call to the PHP code to retrieve and return the innerHTML string. Upon return the JavaScript code would set the innerHTML attribute of the appropriate div element.

Comment: If you have multiple such div elements, you either make multiple calls or one call where an array of strings is returned (a JSON array, of course) -- you need to design this.

Comment: I will *try to*, but it being Saturday evening I probably will not be able to get to this for quite a few hours (since if I don't want my wife to kill me).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209227/discussion-between-vepthy-and-booboo).